# MySQL TIMESTAMPDIFF calculation is incorrect?

Tags: mysql

I have the following code for calculating the employee's time of service:

```
CONCAT(
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, hiredate, NOW())," years, ",
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, hiredate, NOW()) MOD 12," months, ",
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, hiredate, NOW()) MOD 365," days"
) AS EmployLengthActive
```

Most of the time they work fine, but today I noticed they are off?
For example:

- Hire date: 02-21-2005 gives "12 years, 11 months, 2 days"
- Hire date: 03-08-2005 gives "12 years, 11 months, 352 days"

hiredate is MySQL "DateTime type (with 0000-00-00 00:00:00 default)

Is there a better way to calculate the length of time in years/months/days?

Comment: Why do you think they are off? What do you expect to see? How do you account for leap years?

Comment: i believe TIMESTAMPDIFF works correctly with leap years @mustaccio

Comment: You mentioned the `hiredate`, but what was `termdate` for which you got that valu?

Comment: I have updated my post. Thanks to Yusuf, I have removed the termdate as I accidentally posted the code for "InActive" employees! The updated code & question is for "Active" employees only.

Comment: @RaymondNijland `timestampdiff` may be, but `mod 365`?

Comment: If I take out the Mod 12 & Mod 365 I get: 155 months, 4747 days?

Comment: I just figured this out! If I go to the hiredate, and zero out the time part, the calculation is exactly right. Is there a way to disregard the "time" in my code above?